# bluetooth UUID search with Java / bluecove

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

In windows, I communicate fine with my bluetooth connected devices. I get the name and address of the device ok. But, the line

```
UUID[] uuids = device.getUUIDs();
```

… produces this error:

> The method getUUIDs() is undefined for the type RemoteDevice

Code sample

```
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;
//...
LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
DiscoveryAgent discoveryAgent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();
RemoteDevice[] devices = discoveryAgent.retrieveDevices(DiscoveryAgent.PREKNOWN);
UUID[] uuids = device.getUUIDs();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the [RemoteDevice](http://www.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/RemoteDevice.html) class does not have a `getUUIDs()` method. I assume that in your code the `device` is a single member of the `devices` array, otherwise there might still be an error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by others, there is no `getUUID()` method in [RemoteDevice](http://www.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/RemoteDevice.html) class. However, if you need the bluetooth address you can use the [`getBluetoothAddress()`](http://www.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/RemoteDevice.html#getBluetoothAddress()) method like this:

```java
package org.example;

import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BlueTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        DiscoveryAgent discoveryAgent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();
        RemoteDevice[] devices = discoveryAgent.retrieveDevices(DiscoveryAgent.PREKNOWN);
        for (RemoteDevice device : devices) {
            System.out.println("Address: " + device.getBluetoothAddress());
            System.out.println("Name: " + device.getFriendlyName(false));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.