# How to get the UUID of a bluetooth device, preferably with JAVA

Tags: java, bluetooth

I am using the following Java code to successfully discover Bluetooth devices connected to my PC (Windows).

```
import javax.bluetooth.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SimpleTry {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws BluetoothStateException {
    try {
        LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        DiscoveryAgent discoveryAgent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();

        RemoteDevice[] remoteDevices = discoveryAgent.retrieveDevices(DiscoveryAgent.CACHED);

        for (RemoteDevice remoteDevice : remoteDevices) {
            System.out.println("Device Address: " + remoteDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
            System.out.println("Device Name: " + remoteDevice.getFriendlyName(false));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77282130/bluetooth-uuid-search-with-java-bluecove), there is no remoteDevice.getUUID() function.
is there any way to retrieve the UUID of the discovered Bluetooth devices preferably in Java?